# Gtk# in monodevelop not working anymore after upgrading to ubuntu 11.10 unity

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, monodevelop, upgrade, ubuntu-unity

I had some monodevelop programs with a GTK# user interface running smoothly in ubuntu 11.04 without unity. I have upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 with unity. Now I get the following error:

> "The type or namespace name 'Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?".

And indeed in my references the references atk-sharp, gdk-sharp, glade-sharp, glid-sharp, stk-sharp and pango-sharp are colored red and I can't re-add them.

If I search in the software to install at gtk-sharp then it tells me Gtk# 2.10 is installed.
If I start a new gtk project in monodevelop it gives the same errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is due to Mono runtime version. Please change Mono runtime version of the project from Mono/.NET 3.5 to Mono/.NET 4.0 to fix this issue.

For this, please follow the steps as given below:

1. Launch 'Project Options' dialog using Solution Explorer.
2. Select 'General' project settings available under 'Build' group
3. Change Runtime version to Mono/.NET 4.0.
4. MonoDevelop will upgrade the current project as Visual Studio 2010
   equivalents. Then, Rebuild the project and verify the outcome.

Comment: @Karthick, I followed the exact instructions in your answer, and I am experiencing the exact same issue as Paul, but your method did not wrok for me unfortunately. When I create a new Solution (GTK# 2 C# Project) and without making any changes to code, it gives me the same issue as Paul. I have made sure that Mono runtime version is set to Mono/.NET 4.0.Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind :) I just solved it. In Fedora, you need to install more things. Run yum install gtk-sharp2-devel under root at the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

In my case solution was installing GTK# libraries.
For Debian based distros GTK# could be installed as

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-sharp2
```

Or if you are using a RedHat based distro,

```
yum install gtk-sharp2-devel
```

See Tommy's comment above.