# MonoDevelop project build fails with 'The type or namespace 'GDK' could not be found

Tags: c#, macos, monodevelop, gdk

'...are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?'

I tried the solution in this question [Gtk# in monodevelop not working anymore after upgrading to ubuntu 11.10 unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014780/gtk-in-monodevelop-not-working-anymore-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-11-10-unity) but appears to not work here.

I am running on Mtn Lion with lastest MonoFramework 2.10.10 and MonoDevelop 3.1.1

Any suggestions to get build going? Thanks.

Comment: Hamlet you have changed Gdk to Gtk but the build error mentions Gdk.

Comment: Because you try to solve problem using link from post which relates to Gdk#. That's different thinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says exactly what you need to do.

1. Add reference to Gtk# assembly if no one.
2. Add `using Gtk;` to your code.

Comment: But this is an existing project that I've just picked up.

Comment: "I've just picked up" - mean it you copied project to another computer?

Comment: I've just pulled the project from a git repo.

Comment: In your solution explorer have you see valid reference to Gtk# dlls?

Comment: that's it yes it's referencing dlls under a directory "../Program Files/.." somewhere. I have deleted these and added them back in edit references. Compiles now. Thanks.